# How to display only one progress message on upload multiply files on eleme.io [vuejs]

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**Stack**: Vuejs + element.eleme.io

**What we trying todo**: Upload multiply file and display only ***one*** "in progress message".

For uploading images we're using https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/upload#upload

While multiply images are uploading the message must be shown https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/message

If we use on-progress hook, it constantly returns new messages. And we have lots of messages instead of one message.

**Question**: How to display only one progress message while uploading multiply files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using any of the other events? i.e. before upload.

I've made a quick [codepen](https://codepen.io/Shoejep/full/WNvyZJV) which only shows one message when uploading multiple files.

Add this to el-upload

```
:before-upload="beforeUpload"
```

Then add this method

```
beforeUpload(file) {
    this.$message('Your files are uploading...');
}
```

EDIT:

I didn't notice there was multiple notifications being shown. After looking at the [source code](https://github.com/ElemeFE/element/blob/f6df39e8c1ff390da0f0df8ea30b07baf5d457f0/packages/upload/src/upload.vue), it looks like the events are fired for every file. One way around this is to use a debounce function, so that your method only gets called once in a certain period. I've updated the codepen to show this using a 5 second period.

Comment: Hi, Shoejep!

Yes, I've tried :before-upload but it kind of shows all messages one over another https://ibb.co/DfH31Mr

Comment: Updated my answer with a possible solution

Comment: Glad it works. If this answer has solved your question please consider upvoting and [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.